# VS Code on Ubuntu mate RPi3

Tags: raspberry-pi, visual-studio-code

I'm following this link(`http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BuildingVisualStudioCodeOnARaspberryPi3.aspx`) for install VS Code on RPi3(Ubuntu mate_la).

when i command `./script/npm.sh install ~~ ,` stdout/stderr is this.
`https://github.com/ParkDyel/practice/blob/master/docs/scripts_npm_sh_node_v4_2_1.log`

when i command `./script/code.sh` , stdout/stderr is this.
`https://github.com/ParkDyel/practice/blob/master/docs/scirpts_code_sh.log`

even if, command with `sudo`, ocurred simiral error.

Comment: Have you tried to see this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/6442) ?

Comment: after your(Kakami Okatsu) comment, i had try with 
sudo apt-get uninstall nodejs  # uninstall nodejs 4.2.6
wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v6.6.0/node-v6.6.0-linux-armv7l.tar.gz # get latest ARM build
tar -xvf node-v6.6.0-linux-armv7l.tar.gz # extract it
sudo cp node-v6.6.0-linux-armv7l /etc/node6.6 # copy extracted file to /etc folder
sudo ln -s /etc/node6.6/bin/node /usr/bin/node # link the nodejs executable
sudo ln -s /etc/node6.6/bin/npm /usr/bin/npm # link the npm executable
node --version # should output v6.6.0

Comment: but Error is similar the above error file. 

https://github.com/ParkDyel/practice/blob/master/docs/scripts_npm_sh_node_6_2_2.log

https://github.com/ParkDyel/practice/blob/master/docs/scripts_npm_sh_node_6_2_2.log

so I manually install gulf-watch npm, but scrtips/code.sh not work collected.

and then, run code.sh make many error(i forget it logging it..)

and now say cannot find module '~/vscode'

Comment: I think you should post the issue on Github since is not code relevant and doesn't belong to Stack Overflow.

Comment: you're right. thanks!